# How to put an alignat-environment into a table

Tags: tables

I want to put the subsequent code lines in a table. That is, I want to have cases 1 and 2 in the left and cases 3 and 4 in the right column. I have never created a table before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{10}
&\text{case 1} &= \SI{10}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &\qquad\qquad
&\text{case 6} &= \SI{13}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 2} &= \SI{10.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 7} &= \SI{13.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 3} &= \SI{11}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 8} &= \SI{14}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 4} &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 9} &= \SI{14.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 5} &= \SI{12}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 10} &= \SI{15}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you're right. Yours is better. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use further alignment points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
\text{case 1} &= \SI{10}{\giga\hertz}   &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &\qquad\qquad
\text{case 3} &= \SI{11}{\giga\hertz}   &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
\text{case 2} &= \SI{10.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
\text{case 4} &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This was based on a handful of cases; for more of them, here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{6}
&\text{case 1} &&= \SI{10}{\giga\hertz}   &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &\qquad\qquad
&\text{case 6} &&= \SI{11}{\giga\hertz}   &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 2} &&= \SI{10.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 7} &&= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 3} &&= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 8} &&= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 4} &&= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 9} &&= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
&\text{case 5} &&= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
&\text{case 10} &&= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{6}
\text{case }&& 1 &= \SI{10}{\giga\hertz}   &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &\qquad\qquad
\text{case }&& 6 &= \SI{11}{\giga\hertz}   &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
\text{case }&& 2 &= \SI{10.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
\text{case }&& 7 &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
\text{case }&& 3 &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
\text{case }&& 8 &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
\text{case }&& 4 &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
\text{case }&& 9 &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} \\
\text{case }&& 5 &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz} &
\text{case }&& 10 &= \SI{11.5}{\giga\hertz} &&+ \SI{12.5}{\giga\hertz}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx, almost perfect! - I have edited my question a little bit - I want the c of case 10 to be aligned with the c of the other cases as well. At the same time of course the '=' sign should stay aligned. I figured it should work because of the '&' in front of '\text{case}' but it doesn't.

Comment: @Luk Added with two variants

Comment: cool, thx a lot! - can you explain to me what the effect of the double && is when compared to just one & ?

Comment: @Luk `alignat` builds an alignment consisting of pairs of columns; the first column in the pair is right aligned, the second one is left aligned. With `&&` we jump over one column.